# Storing tokens for Amazon SNS in MongoDB

Tags: node.js

I'm starting to set up notifications for iOS devices using Amazon SNS.

In all the guides I'm seeing something like [this](https://tudip.com/blog-post/push-notifications-to-mobile-platforms-using-amazon-sns/)

"For creating SNS topic we need to register all the user’s device tokens with AWS SNS service. We can manage device token when user signup and login to the app and store the device tokens to the database. For each user device, the device token should be unique."

Now I'm not sure whether this means that I should store the token with AWS through the registration process, does it mean that I should store the token in my user object in MongoDB. My User model is currently:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const user = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   email: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
    },
   password: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
    },
   reset_password_token: {
    type: String
   },
   reset_password_expires: {
    type: Date
   }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

So should I add fields for both iOS and Android device push notifications in here, but I don't see why we would need to do that as I can't see we use the token after a one-time subscription during login?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to store the token generated by the application to publish the message to the user later.

I would recommend creating another collection to store those kinds of information linked to the UserId.